# Computing and Storing cosine similarity (dot product) of vectors in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, numpy, matrix, cosine-similarity

I have a table that looks like this -

- **ID** ,
- **Different Table ID** (**foreign key** (one to one connection)),
- **Vector** (**JSONB** array that contain 5000 numerical elements)

Is there a way to compute a dot product between the vectors to the whole matrix? (In this case, the matrix is the whole table when each row is a vector from this table) and then storing it in a different table?

This way, the whole cosine similarity will be pre-computed and stored for a more efficient use.

I thought of maybe iterating over the table in batches and using numpy to store it as a matrix and computing the dot product each time, but I'm not sure if this solution is the correct one because it isn't so efficient.

If you think that there's a better solution of doing it, I will be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer. But I suggest adding the pgvector extension (https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector) to your Postgres database. You will have a new data type "vector" and can measure the similarity of objects of that type using different metrics: L2, dot product and cosine similarity and sort results by the used metric.